# R: Conditional replacement values with different data types

Tags: r

I have a column with text data. I would like to replace that data with a number.

[image]

Example:

```
 REASON

 HomeImp
 HomeImp
 HomeImp
 HomeImp
 HomeImp
 DebtCon
 HomeImp
 DebtCon

 DebtCon
 HomeImp

 DebtCon
 DebtCon
 HomeImp
```

I tried:

```
 REASON[REASON == "HomeImp"] <- 1
```

But it doesn't work, so I guess that the problem is with data types. I just want to change "HomeImp" with a number 1 and "DebtCon" with a -1.

P.S. 'REASON' is just the name of the column.

SOLVED using

```
 REASON <- as.character(REASON)
 REASON[REASON == "HomeImp"] <- '1'
```

Comment: What type of object is `REASON`--a dataframe, matrix, or something else? Can you create a small example version of `REASON` in the question?

Comment: Have you considered converting it to a factor, which would number them automatically (as a simplistic explanation).

Comment: `REASON[REASON == "HomeImp"] <- '1'`

Comment: Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, REASON == "HomeImp", value = "1") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated

Comment: How do you read the data into R? Some data import functions convert data such as these into factors. This can be prevented by `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`. If `REASON` is actually a factor, try `as.numeric(yourdataframe$REASON)` - and see what it gives you.

Comment: Convert the `REASON` column to character values with `as.character`. After that you can use @LyzandeR's code.